# How to detect only when keyboard is being shown?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, rotation

I wanted my UIView to animate to a new position when the keyboard was shown, so used the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification`. The problem is that when the device is rotated without the keyboard, the view has autoresizing and rotates as it should - it looks perfect.

Unfortunately, with the keyboard displayed, rotating the device sends those notifications and thus performing a UIView animation in response gives it an odd animation. It could best be described as looking like it jumps into a new position and is then anchored round by a corner to the new orientation. Perhaps you know what I'm talking about.

Is there any way for me to detect when the device is rotating or otherwise deal with the problem when rotating when the keyboard is being shown?

Comment: Is UIKeyboardWillShowNotification is send when rotating the device? Instead of using UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification you can use UIKeyboardDidShowNotification so it should not be sent when rotating. As the name of the method says it is normal for the UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotofication to be send when the device rotates (because the frame is changed).

Answer (score 0):

For orientation-change detection use the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`.

Comment: That only gets called after it happened. Too late - the animation already happened. If there was a WillChangeNotification, and it was called before the keyboard ones, it'd be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following code will help you..

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)BOOL keyBoardShow;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];


    [super viewDidLoad];
}
-(void)keyboardWillBeShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    keyBoardShow = YES;
}


-(void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    keyBoardShow = NO;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (keyBoardShow) {
        // Do the needful when the keyboard is shown

    }else{

    }
}
```

Just set bool value in keyboardWillBeShown and keyboardWillBeHidden delegate methods. And do your uiview position in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of relying on the built-in notifications, why don't you instead rely on what's triggering the keyboard showing in the first place? I'm guessing the keyboard pops up when a particular UITextField becomes the first responder. You should be able to use that.

Register a delegate for that UITextField and implement -textFieldDidBeginEditing:. The delegate should be a view controller. Then, to keep things loosely coupled, post your own notification from the delegate and have your view registered for that.

It's a bit more work, but it gives you much better control.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

[Apple documentation: UITextFieldDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

Comment: By listening this delegate call it's not possible to retrieve keyboard appearance animation details. If you want to animate your content with keyboard - which is the best UX - you have to listen `UIKeyboard...` notifications and get appearance details from notification's userInfo dictionary.